# Discord.Net C# Не работает команда mute

Tags: c#

При попытке ввести команду
`.help`

Выдает ошибку
`User Not Found`

Код:

```
[Command("mute")]
        [RequireBotPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        public async Task Mute(SocketGuildUser user, [Remainder] double time)
        {
            if (time > 60)
            {
                var builder = new EmbedBuilder();
                builder.WithAuthor(Context.Client.CurrentUser);
                builder.WithFooter(footer => footer.Text = Context.User.Username);
                builder.WithTitle("**Oh, no!**");
                builder.AddField("Error", "Максимальное время мута: 60 минут", true);
                builder.WithCurrentTimestamp();
                await ReplyAsync(embed: builder.Build());
            }
            else
            {
                var builder = new EmbedBuilder();
                builder.WithAuthor(Context.Client.CurrentUser);
                builder.WithFooter(footer => footer.Text = Context.User.Username);
                builder.WithTitle("**Успешно!**");
                builder.WithDescription($"{user.Mention} замучен на {time} минут");
                builder.WithCurrentTimestamp();
                await ReplyAsync(embed: builder.Build());
                await user.SetTimeOutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(time));
            }
        }
```

В настройках все включено
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Я думаю проблема не в том коде который вы показываете, а в том, который вы нам не показали. Скорее всего ваш `user`, который вы передаете в метод, попросту отстуствует на сервере или вы неправильно передаете его `id` (или что-то другое которое идентифицирует юзера)

Comment: Я передаю через пинг пользователя ( он на сервере есть)

Comment: Работает через раз